# SQL Server query results as INSERT

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to concatenate lastName(3 letters) + firstName(2 letters) to create a new username. When I used this script, it created new records for the concatenation results.

```
USE [database]
INSERT INTO table (username)
SELECT SUBSTRING(lastName, 1, 3) + SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 2)
FROM [database].[dbo].table
```

Could someone show me how to append the original record with the new username?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an update instead of an insert. The following will update all records with the new username. If you want a more specific update for just a single record, you will need a WHERE clause to identify the particular rows.

```
UPDATE table
SET username = SubString(lastName, 1, 3) + SubString(firstName, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
UPDATE table
SET username = SUBSTRING(lastName, 1, 3) + SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 2)
```

This updates the `username` of every record in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
USE [database]

UPDATE MyTable
SET USERNAME = SUBSTRING(lastName, 1, 3) + SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change the user name on the existing records, use `update` instead of `insert`:

```
UPDATE table
   SET username = SUBSTRING(lastName, 1, 3) + SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 2);
```

If you want to insert new rows for the same users with more columns, add them to the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO table (username, col1, col2, . . ., coln)
SELECT SUBSTRING(lastName, 1, 3) + SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 2),
       col1, col2, . . ., coln
FROM [database].[dbo].table;
```